# Is it the Correct way to create an XML like this:

Tags: c#, dom, xmldocument

I want to create something like this at run-time:

```
  <CWS>
    <Case name="10-040-00022">
      <CaseDetailsSet>
        <CaseDetail title="Patient name" /> 
        <CaseDetail title="Date of birth" /> 
      </CaseDetailsSet>
    </Case>
  </CWS>
```

so I wrote something like this ( I wish to use DOM in .NET .. not the XMLWriter,etc)

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("CWS");
    XmlElement singleCase = doc.CreateElement("Case");

    root.AppendChild(singleCase);

    singleCase.SetAttribute("name", "10-040-00022");

    XmlElement CaseDetailsSet = doc.CreateElement("CaseDetailsSet");
    singleCase.AppendChild(CaseDetailsSet);

    XmlElement CaseDetail = doc.CreateElement("CaseDetail");
    CaseDetailsSet.AppendChild(CaseDetail);
    CaseDetail.SetAttribute("title", "Patient Name");
```

please have a look at it and tell me if I am oing something wrong , regardign the code I worte to create that structure above.

much appreciated.

Comment: Is the code not writing the document you would expect? Or are you looking for best practise advice?

Comment: You might want to check out Linq-to-XML.  Creating XML is much easier plus you get the goodness of Linq if needed.

Comment: @juharr - It is a wonder I put up with those DOM classes for so long.

Comment: @ Brabster: I hope it is working, have not done enough study yet to know how actually write it to disk and see if it what I want. and yes I am looking for best practice advice in this regard as well

Comment: @juharr: how is the learning curve for your advice to just learn as enough to achieve my goal? it is a project with deadlines which is end of today :D.. you know :D

Comment: @BDotA That's a pretty tight schedule to learn it.  Not sure if you'd have enough time to learn it and convert your code (depending on how much of it uses the old DOM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. You'll need to append the root to the XmlDocument.
2. You need to add the second CaseDetail.

   ```
   XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

   XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("CWS");

   doc.AppendChild(root); // Append the root element to the XmlDocument

   XmlElement singleCase = doc.CreateElement("Case");

   root.AppendChild(singleCase);

   singleCase.SetAttribute("name", "10-040-00022");

   XmlElement CaseDetailsSet = doc.CreateElement("CaseDetailsSet");
   singleCase.AppendChild(CaseDetailsSet);

   XmlElement CaseDetail = doc.CreateElement("CaseDetail");
   CaseDetailsSet.AppendChild(CaseDetail);
   CaseDetail.SetAttribute("title", "Patient Name");

   // add the second case detail
   XmlElement CaseDetailDateOfBirth = doc.CreateElement("CaseDetail");
   CaseDetailsSet.AppendChild(CaseDetailDateOfBirth);
   CaseDetailDateOfBirth.SetAttribute("title", "Date of birth");
   ```

Comment: To save it to the disk, doc.Save(@"c:\case.xml");

Comment: thanks Sir, I was so worried about the ROOT that if I have done it wrong.

Comment: Just looking at this makes me a bit ill.

Comment: Thanks, so we do not need to use XMLNode anywhere in the code? that is intresting , creating everything with XMLElement and setting the correct parent for it is doing the job... nice....

Comment: @ChaosPandion: agreed. All I tried to do was point out the problem with the code.

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I'd show how to do this with Linq-to-XML

```
XElement doc = new XElement("CWS",
    new XElement("Case",
        new XAttribute("name", "10-040-00022"),
        new XElement("CaseDetailSet",
            new XElement("CaseDetail",
                new XAttribute("title", "Patient name")),
            new XElement("CaseDetail",
                new XAttribute("title", "Date of birth")))));
```

Comment: thank you so very much. this helps what do I need to know about for this purpose. thank again and WOW... this LINQ is so Cool to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem with your code. If it creates the xml you want, it should be ok. There are many different ways of creating xml documents, yours seems to be okay.